# Should one avoid using Hudson CI as a queue service?

Tags: queue, hudson

I realize Hudson was not designed as a queue service per se - and that there are other projects like RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ, etc.

We were recently in a situation where we needed to set up a windows executable as a web service with queuing. Because of the platform, time constraints, and my familiarity with Hudson I said : "Hudson can do that" - we trigger a little perl script that runs the executable, and then hits a callback URL. It's been great. We get a nice record of jobs processed. If we needed to scale up we could add slave machines, and the queuing works perfectly.

I have not seen any discussions on using Hudson as a queue service, so I'm looking for reason *not* to do it for future projects.

Comment: This is a stab in the dark because I'm not familar with Hudson or exactly what you're trying to do, but you mention Windows - [MSMQ is Microsoft's queing service](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/techinfo/overview/msmqfaq.mspx). If you do need an alternative, could that be viable? It's included in every version of Windows (inc. desktops I believe) except Web Server.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your needs. The happy scenario works fine. What happens if you have 10 items in the Hudson queue and Hudson shuts down. The queue will be lost. Is this acceptable for you? If not, you have to implement a persistence layer. Are you now still better off with Hudson or should you use a product designed for queueing?

These are just some questions that you need to answer yourself.

Comment: Good point.

The other two features that have come to mind are rate limiting and retries... any others?

Comment: Not really, I am mainly working with Hudson. If I were you, I would create a list of requirements and nice to have and determine if you can easily implement this with Hudson. Since you seem to struggle with the features you might need, get some feature lists of queue service products and decide which features you need.